# Making axis guide lines over an image that follow the mouse pointer

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, mouseover

I have a PNG image of a graph on an HTML page.

I'm hoping to include a set of superimposed x and y guide-lines that appear on mouse over, whose vertex follows the mouse pointer, in order to help users read values on the x and y axes.

For example, they use such an effect on WolframAlpha (doesn't work in IE<8 though): 
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph+y%3D2x

Does anyone have any ideas on how to accomplish this, javascript or otherwise? I believe WolframAlpha is somehow using the HTML5 canvas if that helps (see screenshot below).

[image: Screenshot.]

Although if there's a way to avoid using canvas in order to support IE8, that would be excellent. The gridlines could certainly also extend off the image boundary and across the whole page, if that would make it easier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a simple implementation

CSS

```
#imageholder div{ background-color:black;position:absolute; }
#imageholder{;position:relative;display:inline-block;overflow:hidden; }
#horizontal{width:100%;height:1px;}
#vertical{width:1px;height:100%;}
```

JS(use of jquery)

```
$('#imageholder img').on('mousemove', null, [$('#horizontal'), $('#vertical')],function(e){
    e.data[1].css('left', e.offsetX==undefined?e.originalEvent.layerX:e.offsetX);
    e.data[0].css('top', e.offsetY==undefined?e.originalEvent.layerY:e.offsetY);
});
$('#imageholder').on('mouseenter', null, [$('#horizontal'), $('#vertical')], function(e){
    e.data[0].show();
    e.data[1].show();
}).on('mouseleave', null, [$('#horizontal'), $('#vertical')], function(e){
        e.data[0].hide();
        e.data[1].hide();
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="imageholder">
    <div id="horizontal"></div>
    <div id="vertical"></div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/320x280">
</div>
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ovinun/)

Also with lines that goes across the page [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ugupuk/)